# Approximating weight of individual items from sum of their weight

Tags: linear-regression

### Problem

I have a list of orders, approximation of their total weight and list of items they contain. I need to determine approximate weight of individual items.

In other words, I have a few thousand of equations like these:
$$
\begin{cases}
    3x_{110} ~+ & x_{242} ~+ &5x_{412} = 82.5 \\
    8x_{784} ~+ &4x_{124} ~+ &2x_{872} = 49.2 \\
    1x_{784} ~+ & x_{124} ~+ &x_{847} = 120.2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
And I need to find approximate values of $x$, such that the sum of squared errors would be minimal. It seems to me like my problem is a Matrix formulation of Ordinary least squares. Is this correct?

May I ask for advice on how to **practically** calculate this for thousands of equations with thousands of variables?

#### What I've tried

- I've tried using [solver in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040), but that didn't work because it's limited to 200 variables.
- I've tried generating [the equations in GNU MathProg](https://pastebin.pl/view/30f49174) and using an [online solver](https://online-optimizer.appspot.com/), but the results don't seem to be accurate enough, as this solver supports only strictly linear equations (i.e. no absolute value, no squared errors).